# CRC-32 implementation in java.util.zip.CRC32

Tags: java, crc, crc32

Which CRC-32 algorithm is used in the Java CRC-32 class ? The java doc does not give any details. What is the polynomail used and the initial value for calculaton ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [source](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/zip/CRC32-source.html):

> Computes CRC32 data checksum of a data stream.  The actual CRC32
>   algorithm is described in RFC 1952   (GZIP file format specification
>   version 4.3).   Can be used to get the CRC32 over a stream if used
>   with checked input/output streams.

The RFC1952 can be found [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt), but presents a quite technical read.

The initial value for the CRC is `0xFFFFFFFF`, and the CRC table is built the first time the class is loaded on the VM.

Comment: [link](http://regregex.bbcmicro.net/crc-catalogue.htm) says Init value is 0xFFFFFFFF. Im confused !

Comment: Dunxton, if you initialize a new `CRC32` object with no content and call `getValue()`, it will return `0 & 0xffffffffL` which equals `0`. Not sure if that's what OP meant?

Comment: I tried this [link](http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html). For the polynomial 0x04C11DB7 I enter initial value as 0 but the result is not correct. When I try 0XFFFFFFFF I get the expected value.

Answer (score 7):

CRC-32 is a indicated in the package docs for [java.util.zip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) to be specified in [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952#section-8). RFC 1952 defines CRC32 as specified in ISO 3309 which I could not find a free copy of to link you to. However RFC 1952 also indicates that section 8.1.1.6.2 of [ITU-T recommendation V.42](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.42-200203-I/en) specifies the same implementation.

In partcular the polynomial being used is

```
x^32 + x^26 + x^23 + x^22 + x^16 + x^12 + x^11 + x^10 + x^8 + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1
```

Comment: I generate the CRC32 using Java class, but I need to explain the algorithm used to the receiver who is not using java. Will I be correct if I give him the following details ? ISO/IEC 3309 compliant 32 bit CRC algorithm
Polynomial used is 0x04C11DB7 
Initial value would be 0

Answer (score 4):

Using some tools from Internet ( http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html ) I've found a combination of CRC32 parameters that gives the same results as obtained from Java:

- Input reflected, result reflected.
- Polynomial: 0x04C11DB7.
- Initial value: 0xFFFFFFFF.
- Final XOR: 0xFFFFFFFF

Answer (score 1):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9004157/365596) is incorrect.

The initial value for Java's CRC32 class is 0, not 0xFFFFFFFF, as can be seen in the source code for the reset function:

```
/**
 * Resets CRC-32 to initial value.
 */
public void reset() {
    crc = 0;
}
```

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/zip/CRC32.java#L81

I did a quick brute-force search, and it turns out that updating the CRC with the value `0xFFFFFFFF` will actually yield that same value. So if you'd like the CRC32 algorithm to have the initial value `0XFFFFFFFF`, just do:

```
    CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
    // Set the initial value to 0xFFFFFFFF
    crc.update(new byte[]{(byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF});

    System.out.println("CRC: " + crc.getValue());  // prints 4294967295, which is 0xFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: What you are looking at is an implementation detail. CRC32 is defined to output the ones complement. Therefore, `new CRC32().getValue() == 0` is the expected result for an initial value of `0xFFFFFFFF` (since `~0xFFFFFFFF == 0`). The implementation probably just takes the shortcut to calculate everything in the ones complement already, so the output doesn't have to do anything. That's also why `reset()` sets `crc = 0` and not `crc = 0xFFFFFFFF`.