# Different CRC32 values in Java and Go

Tags: java, security, go, checksum, crc32

I'm in the process of writing a utility in Go which can be used to calculate CRC32 checksum of an input string. A similar utility exists in Java which we are using extensively and has been working well for us.

The Java Utility uses `java.util.zip.CRC32` to calculate the checksum. Pseudo code is as follows :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Checksum checksum = new CRC32();
        byte[] input1Bytes = "input1".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        checksum.update(input1Bytes, 0, input1Bytes.length);
        final byte[] input2Bytes = "input2".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        checksum.update(input2Bytes, 0, input2Bytes.length);
        final byte[] input3Bytes = "input3".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        checksum.update(input3Bytes, 0, input3Bytes.length);
        System.out.println("Checksum in Java : " + checksum.getValue());
    }
```

The utility in Go uses the `crc32` from the `hash` package of the Go SDK (version 1.13.6) (`import "hash/crc32"`)
Pseudo code for generating the checksum in Go is as follows :

```
    table := crc32.MakeTable(0)
    checksum := crc32.Checksum([]byte("input1"), table)
    checksum = crc32.Update(checksum, table, []byte("input2"))
    checksum = crc32.Update(checksum, table, []byte("input3"))
    log.Printf("Checksum in go : %v", checksum)
```

The output from the Java code is :

```
Checksum in Java : 2705255531
```

The output from the Go code is :

```
Checksum in go : 4294967295
```

I've also compared the byte arrays being generated in the 3 steps and they have the same values.

What am i missing and how do I ensure this mismatch is handled?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Is not 4294967295 = 0xFFFF_FFFF? Then golang seems off.

Comment: The call `crc32.MakeTable(0)` is clearly wrong: you're setting the polynomial to zero. Which polynomial did you want? (Zero is never right.) See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/9004016/1256452

Comment: Thanks a lot @JoopEggen and @torek for your response.

You're right @torek, `crc32.MakeTable(0)` is the issue. I changed it to `table := crc32.IEEETable` and it seems to be working. Will be running tests on this to ensure this covers all the aspects.

Comment: Yes, that looks like it is the right one. Note that the `hash/crc32` code uses a little-endian (or bit-reversed) polynomial, hence `0x04C11DB7` is not right. Bit-reversing `0x04C11DB7`, however, produces `0xedb88320` which is `crc32.IEEE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the same polynomial as your Java code, and you get the same results.

The most common CRC-32 polynomial is there in the [`crc32`](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/crc32/#IEEE) package as a constant: `crc32.IEEE = 0xedb88320`:

```
table := crc32.MakeTable(crc32.IEEE)
```

With this change you get the same result. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DaXjxZU8GRN).

Comment: thank you! figured this after Torek added a comment.